# how to change Firestore Collection with Menu inflator?

Tags: java, android, firebase, menuitem, google-cloud-firestore

I have Some Different Collection in My Cloud Firestore,

1. ProjectList1
2. ProjectList2
3. ++

I want to switch them with Menu Item, but In 'firestore.collection' i sat only **ProjectList1**, now how can i set or switch **ProjectList2 or ProjectList3**
in firestore.collection(ProjectList1)..

*Code is bellow:*

```
mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    mFirestore.collection("ProjectList1").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

            if(e !=null){
                Log.d(TAG,"Error :"+ e.getMessage());
            }
            for (DocumentChange doc : documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {

                if (doc.getType()==DocumentChange.Type.ADDED){
                    Prjs prjs = doc.getDocument().toObject(Prjs.class);
                    prjList.add(prjs);
                   csListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                }
            }
        }
    });
```

And i tried to switch in Menu, but not working properly, it keeping all previous data first..

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

         case R.id.pro1:
 mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

mFirestore.collection("ProjectList1").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

        if(e !=null){
            Log.d(TAG,"Error :"+ e.getMessage());
        }
        for (DocumentChange doc : documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {

            if (doc.getType()==DocumentChange.Type.ADDED){
                Prjs prjs = doc.getDocument().toObject(Prjs.class);
                prjList.add(prjs);
               csListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        }
    }
});
        return true;

        case R.id.pro2:
mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

mFirestore.collection("ProjectList2").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

        if(e !=null){
            Log.d(TAG,"Error :"+ e.getMessage());
        }
        for (DocumentChange doc : documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {

            if (doc.getType()==DocumentChange.Type.ADDED){
                Prjs prjs = doc.getDocument().toObject(Prjs.class);
                prjList.add(prjs);
               csListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            }
        }
    }
});
         return true;
            default:
}        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the data in the existing list before adding more from Firebase

```
prjList.clear()
```